# is a variable gitignore for heroku possible?

Tags: git, heroku, github

I need essentially 2 different git ignores for heroku. I've resolved this before but have forgotten. How do I get this to work gracefully so I can just push to and pippe through github?

### .gitignore

```
## heroku
#node_modules/*
#!node_modules/vue/dist/vue.js
#!node_modules/vuex/dist/vuex.js
#!node_modules/vue-router/dist/vue-router.js
#npm-debug.log
#serverCredentials.json
#public/config.js
##dist/*
#.idea/*

## dev
node_modules/*
!node_modules/vue/dist/vue.js
!node_modules/vuex/dist/vuex.js
!node_modules/vue-router/dist/vue-router.js
npm-debug.log
#serverCredentials.json
#public/config.js
#dist/*
.idea/*
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot do this. Gitignore rules are static and never change.

Also: based on your code sample above, I think you are approaching this wrong. If you'ure using Heroku to deploy your app, you still want to ignore the exact same values.

What gitignore does is prevent files from being added to a Git repository. On Heroku, you're just READING a Git repository, never saving anything, so it makes no sense at all to enforce different rules there.

What you should do is use something like environment variables to control behavior differences on your environments.

Comment: No,  those files give access to an api. I don't want to publish them for all to see on github,  but I do want the server on heroku to access and safely transmit data from the api.  Still this was a good answer. Apparently I need to write a bash script 2 change to gitignore file conditionally.  Thanks